# How to parse the JSON response in Phone Gap?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

I am new to phone gap and i gone through similar questions related to parsing the JSON data.

I am not getting enough explanation from those questions

Here is my code i used to fetch the JSON response

```
function GetData() {
  var jqxhr = $.getJSON('http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username=demo', parseResult)
  .error(function () {
    alert('error');
  });
}

function parseResult(tx) {
  alert("Success");
  alert(JSON.status.itemList);
  var data = JSON.parse(tx);
  alert(data);  
}
```

I want to know how to display the received data in alertview and also to know how to parse the response.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You already getting the response in JSON format only so no need to parse it

```
$(document).read(function(){
$.ajax({
url:'http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON',
type:'post',
data:{"postalcode":"6600","country":"AT" },
dataType:'json',
success:function(output)

$.each(output,function(key,value){
   alert(value.status);
},error:function(err){alert(err);}

});
});
```

This is for 1D array....